# JavaME: how to detect headphones plugin and plugout?

Tags: audio, java-me

I meant wired headphones which are connected through an audio jack.
It would be great to get a code example!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this with standard Java ME APIs.

Comment: It is possible to monitor the changes in audio monitoring using proprietary API only.  For example, to do this for Symbian devices see the following link:  http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-4277A663-9D86-4E8E-8384-662BFEFBB395.html